# How to pass a variable from View Controller to App Delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class within my AppDelegate.m file called PAEAudioHost which I am using to play audio, and I want to stop the audio file using a UIButton in my Detail:Controller.m file.

To stop and start the audio file you use the public member functions:

```
void (start)
void (stop)
```

I have tried the following code in the detail controller:

```
 P11AppDelegate* app =[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.host stop]
```

This produces an error stating: "Property 'host' not found on object of type 'DetailController *'"

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

host (PAEAudioHost) is a public property insite your AppDelegate? So:

```
P11AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.host stop]
```

**EDIT:**

You should have a public property called host into AppDelegate.h:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) PAEAudioHost *host;
```

Comment: It needs to be cast: P11AppDelegate* app =  (P11AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

Comment: This answer produced a couple of errors. The first states: "property with 'retain or (strong)' attribute must be of object type" and the second states: "unknown type name 'PAEAudioHost'

Comment: You said: `I have a class within my AppDelegate.m file called PAEAudioHost`. You explained it wrong. Show all your and we can help you.